# Query to get the Transpose of table in SQL server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I know i have not wrote question properly so will will explain it here in detail.

I have table TrnOutlet with following structure

```
                Retailer    Flag    Date
            ------------------------------------------------------------
                26901032    3     2012-05-05 00:00:00
                26901032    1     2012-04-28 00:00:00
                26901032    2     2012-04-21 00:00:00
                26901032    3     2012-04-20 00:00:00
                26901033    1     2012-04-28 00:00:00
                26901033    3     2012-04-28 00:00:00
                26901033    1     2012-04-21 00:00:00
                26901033    1     2012-04-20 00:00:00
```

I want output to be

```
        RetailerId  Flag Date flag date flag date....
        ------------------------------------------------------------

        RetailerID1 flag1 Date1 flag2 Date2 ...... flagn Daten
        RetailerID2 flag1 Date1 flag2 Date2 ...... flagn Daten
        .
        .
        .
        RetailerIDn flag1 Date1 flag2 Date2 ...... flagn Daten
```

**OUTPUT WILL BE**

```
        RetailerId  Flag Date      flag date       flag    date      flag   date
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        26901032     3   2012-05-05 1   2012-04-28  2    2012-04-21   3    2012-04-20 
        26901032     1   2012-04-28 3   2012-04-28  1    2012-04-21   1    2012-04-20
```

**NOTE: Date and Flag can be duplicate like as we can see in the above example**

**EDIT:**
    **Query I have Used**

```
select retailerId,BeatId,
    MAX(case when TransactDate <> getDate() then TransactDate else '' end ) as Transactdate,
    MAX(case when CompleteFlag in ('1','2','3') then completeFlag else '' end) as completeFlag
    from TrnOutletHistory
    group by TransactDate,RetailerID,BeatID
    order by retailerID desc
```

Comment: i have tried pivot but i dont know it would possible from pivot as i am not getting output from that method.

Comment: If you have tried pivot, where is your query so that we can help you to possibly fix it?

Comment: Hi David sorry i have tried the above query.

Comment: Don't see any 'pivot' in that query ...

Comment: Yes I have not used pivot but is it possible???

Comment: You have a variable number of columns so the query has to be constructed dynamically. Here's a blog where it's described how to do it: http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx